Vegalite Map Slider for a year update is not working
I m trying to add slider for a year.
However, It only shows the data when the data is 2022.
I m not sure how to fix this kind of issue.
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Water Consumption for Domestic and Non-Domestic in Malaysia by State (Million Liters per Day, 2003-2022)",
    "subtitle": "Data for W.P. Kuala Lumpur and W.P. Putrajaya are subsumed under Selangor.",
    "font": "serif",
    "fontSize": 17,
    "align": "center",
    "subtitleFont": "serif",
    "subtitleFontSize": 14,
    "subtitleColor": "gray"
  },
  "width": 700,
  "height": 400,
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "Year_selection",
      "value": 2019,
      "bind": {
        "input": "range",
        "min": 2003,
        "max": 2022,
        "step": 1,
        "name": "Year: "
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Sector_selection",
      "value": "overall",
      "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "options": ["overall", "domestic", "nondomestic"],
        "name": "Sector: "
      }
    }
  ],
  "projection": {
    "type": "equalEarth",
    "scale": 2200,
    "center": [109, 3.8]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junistz-dev/2024_Data_Vis_Project2/refs/heads/main/country%20detail%20json/output.json",
        "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "my"}
      },
      "mark": {
              "type": "geoshape",
              "stroke": "white",
              "strokeWidth":0.8
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "lookup": "properties.name",
          "from":{
            "data": {
              "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junistz-dev/2024_Data_Vis_Project2/refs/heads/main/0.water_consumption.csv",
              "format": {"type": "csv"}
            },
            "key": "state",
            "fields": ["state","sector","value","year"]
          }
        },
        {
          "filter": "datum.year == Year_selection"
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "color":{
          "field": "value",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Water Consumption in Million (L)",
          "scale": {"scheme": "yellowgreenblue"}
        },
      "tooltip": [
        {"field": "properties.name", "type": "nominal", "title": "State: "},
        {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Million Liters per Day: "}
      ]
      }  
        
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "stroke": "transparent"
    }
  }
}

I tried to see is my csv file has error, and is my slider function is wrong.
But i think there was no issue.
I assume the. "filter": "datum.year == Year_selection" part is somehow wrong.
